# Reading hashmap from file using key

Tags: hashmap, key, serializable

I have a serialized file HashmapSent.ser, which contains a hashmap in below format

```
HashMap<String, RequestData> sentHashmap,
```

where RequestData is a POJO I created.

My question here is.., Is it possible to read the hashmap from file using the key.

When I use ObjectInputStream.readObject(), I guess it will load whole hashmap in the file into Memory. As the Hashmap contains 10000s of key value pair, it would be good if I could read/load the particular record using key.

Could anybody please help me with this.

Comment: Sorry!!  Hashmap format is 

HashMap<String, RequestData> sentHashmap

Answer (score 0):

I think this is imppssible to achieved ,because HashMap is a class in Java,didn't mean anything in a file. Maybe we can say a file means a string to Java,if you want to search the file with a key,the string must have is own regular.For example:json,xml,sqlite and so on.

Another import thing is we need to load whole file into memory.We can choose xml or sqlite in the example above.

Json:Json need to load whole file into memory.
XML:dom4j needs too.
XML:Sax didn't need to load whole file.
sqlite:you just need to connect to the database

That's what is think to solve the problem.